# Fixed wakeup from suspend - want to understand why it worked?

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, nvidia, suspend

I have a Dell laptop with both Intel integrated graphics but using NVIDIA as my main.

I feel this is important for my already solved problem for me an unknown reason.

What I did was to read to Reddit and LinuxMint forums that I should add a strange parameter:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
```

to replace a blank one (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`).

I find it weird for I am NOT using Nouveau drivers for ages, I use the proprietary ones (currently of version 495 from the official repo).

---

Dropplets:

```
$ lspci -vvv | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

---

I am now able to wake up from suspend on my Linux Mint 20.2.

But,... Why did this solution work, please? Thank you for any direction!

---

All system info with only sensitive filtered:

```
$ sudo inxi --verbosity 8 --filter

System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-91-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-91-generic 
           root=UUID=f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa ro nouveau.modeset=0 quiet splash 
           fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes ipv6.disable=1 
           Desktop: Cinnamon 5.0.7 wm: muffin 5.0.2 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 20.2 Uma 
           base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Inspiron 7577 v: N/A serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0J8HMF v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: 1.15.0 date: 10/08/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 29.3 Wh condition: 29.3/56.0 Wh (52%) volts: 15.8/15.2 
           model: Samsung SDI DELL W7NKD7B type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Full 
Memory:    RAM: total: 31.11 GiB used: 2.89 GiB (9.3%) 
           Array-1: capacity: 32 GiB slots: 2 EC: None max module size: 16 GiB note: est. 
           Device-1: DIMM A size: 16 GiB speed: 2400 MT/s type: DDR4 
           detail: synchronous unbuffered (unregistered) bus width: 64 bits total: 64 bits 
           manufacturer: 0198000080AD part-no: KHX2400C14S4/16G serial: <filter> 
           Device-2: DIMM B size: 16 GiB speed: 2400 MT/s type: DDR4 
           detail: synchronous unbuffered (unregistered) bus width: 64 bits total: 64 bits 
           manufacturer: 0198000080AD part-no: KHX2400C14S4/16G serial: <filter> 
PCI Slots: Slot: 4 type: x1 PCI Express Slot5 status: In Use length: Short 
           Slot: 5 type: x1 PCI Express Slot6 status: In Use length: Short 
           Slot: 6 type: x1 PCI Express Slot7 status: Available length: Short 
           Slot: 7 type: 32-bit PCI Slot8 status: Available length: Short 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-7700HQ bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake family: 6 
           model-id: 9E (158) stepping: 9 microcode: EA L1 cache: 256 KiB L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           L3 cache: 6144 KiB bogomips: 44798 
           Speed: 900 MHz min/max: 800/3800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 900 2: 900 3: 900 4: 900 5: 900 
           6: 900 7: 900 8: 900 
           Flags: 3dnowprefetch abm acpi adx aes aperfmperf apic arat arch_perfmon art avx avx2 bmi1 bmi2 
           bts clflush clflushopt cmov constant_tsc cpuid cpuid_fault cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts 
           epb ept ept_ad erms est f16c flexpriority flush_l1d fma fpu fsgsbase fxsr ht hwp hwp_act_window 
           hwp_epp hwp_notify ibpb ibrs ida intel_pt invpcid invpcid_single lahf_lm lm mca mce md_clear 
           mmx monitor movbe mpx msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl nx pae pat pbe pcid pclmulqdq pdcm pdpe1gb pebs 
           pge pln pni popcnt pse pse36 pti pts rdrand rdseed rdtscp rep_good sdbg sep smap smep ss ssbd 
           sse sse2 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 stibp syscall tm tm2 tpr_shadow tsc tsc_adjust tsc_deadline_timer 
           vme vmx vnmi vpid x2apic xgetbv1 xsave xsavec xsaveopt xsaves xtopology xtpr 
           Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: Split huge pages 
           Type: l1tf mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable 
           Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable 
           Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
           Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
           Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
           Type: spectre_v2 
           mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling 
           Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode 
           Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 630 vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           chip ID: 8086:591b 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] vendor: Dell driver: nvidia v: 495.44 
           bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1c20 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 495.44 
           direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel CM238 HD Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           chip ID: 8086:a171 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 01:00.1 chip ID: 10de:10f1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-91-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Dell driver: r8169 
           v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 3b:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: enp59s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 3c:00.0 
           chip ID: 8086:24fd 
           IF: wlp60s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           IP v4: <filter> type: noprefixroute scope: global broadcast: <filter> 
           WAN IP: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.38 TiB used: 650.94 GiB (46.2%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Toshiba model: KXG50ZNV512G NVMe 512GB size: 476.94 GiB block size: 
           physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> rev: AADA4107 
           temp: 27 C scheme: GPT 
           SMART: yes health: PASSED on: 2y 134d 6h cycles: 2,512 read-units: 71,563,628 [36.6 TB] 
           written-units: 47,533,411 [24.3 TB] 
           ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 870 QVO 1TB size: 931.51 GiB block size: 
           physical: 512 B logical: 512 B sata: 3.3 speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial: <filter> rev: 2B6Q temp: 22 C 
           scheme: GPT 
           SMART: yes state: enabled health: PASSED on: 72d 5h cycles: 279 written: 1.95 TiB 
           Message: No Optical or Floppy data was found. 
RAID:      Message: No RAID data was found. 
Partition: ID-1: / raw size: 476.85 GiB size: 468.36 GiB (98.22%) used: 291.75 GiB (62.3%) fs: ext4 
           block size: 4096 B dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 label: N/A uuid: f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa 
           ID-2: /boot/efi raw size: 94.0 MiB size: 92.5 MiB (98.44%) used: 5.2 MiB (5.6%) fs: vfat 
           block size: 512 B dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 label: N/A uuid: 4966-E925 
           ID-3: /mnt/windows raw size: 930.34 GiB size: 930.34 GiB (100.00%) used: 359.18 GiB (38.6%) 
           fs: ntfs block size: 4096 B dev: /dev/sda3 label: windows10 uuid: 01D480EF7EDA45C0 
           ID-4: /snap/bare/5 raw size: 4 KiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) fs: squashfs 
           dev: /dev/loop0 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-5: /snap/core/11798 raw size: 99.4 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) fs: squashfs 
           dev: /dev/loop1 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-6: /snap/core/11993 raw size: 99.4 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) fs: squashfs 
           dev: /dev/loop2 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-7: /snap/core18/2246 raw size: 55.5 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) fs: squashfs 
           dev: /dev/loop3 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-8: /snap/core18/2253 raw size: 55.5 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) fs: squashfs 
           dev: /dev/loop4 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-9: /snap/core20/1169 raw size: 61.8 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) fs: squashfs 
           dev: /dev/loop8 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-10: /snap/core20/1242 raw size: 61.8 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) 
           fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop16 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-11: /snap/gimp/372 raw size: 276.7 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) fs: squashfs 
           dev: /dev/loop11 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-12: /snap/gimp/380 raw size: 277.0 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) fs: squashfs 
           dev: /dev/loop15 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-13: /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145 raw size: 162.9 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) 
           fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop12 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-14: /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161 raw size: 164.8 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) 
           fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop17 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-15: /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/76 raw size: 242.3 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) 
           fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop5 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-16: /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87 raw size: 247.9 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) 
           fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop13 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-17: /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515 raw size: 65.1 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) 
           fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop10 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-18: /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519 raw size: 65.2 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) 
           fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop14 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-19: /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13 raw size: 140 KiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) 
           fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop7 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-20: /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9 raw size: 132 KiB size: N/A (hidden?) used: N/A (hidden?) 
           fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop6 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-21: /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32 raw size: 260.7 MiB size: N/A (hidden?) 
           used: N/A (hidden?) fs: squashfs dev: /dev/loop9 label: N/A uuid: N/A 
Unmounted: ID-1: /dev/sda1 size: 500.0 MiB fs: vfat label: ESP uuid: 889B-32CC 
           ID-2: /dev/sda2 size: 128.0 MiB fs: N/A label: N/A uuid: N/A 
           ID-3: /dev/sda4 size: 571.7 MiB fs: ntfs label: N/A uuid: 01D78D23F78B6B00 
USB:       Hub: 1-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 16 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s chip ID: 1d6b:0002 
           Hub: 1-1:2 info: Terminus Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s chip ID: 1a40:0101 
           Device-1: 1-1.3:4 info: Logitech M105 Optical Mouse type: Mouse driver: hid-generic,usbhid 
           interfaces: 1 rev: 2.0 speed: 1.5 Mb/s chip ID: 046d:c077 
           Device-2: 1-4:3 info: Intel type: Bluetooth driver: btusb interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s 
           chip ID: 8087:0a2b 
           Device-3: 1-8:5 info: Shenzhen Goodix Fingerprint Reader type: Abstract (modem),CDC-Data 
           driver: cdc_acm interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s chip ID: 27c6:5301 serial: <filter> 
           Device-4: 1-12:6 info: Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD type: Video driver: uvcvideo interfaces: 2 
           rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s chip ID: 0c45:6a08 
           Hub: 2-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 8 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s chip ID: 1d6b:0003 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 44.0 C mobo: 41.0 C sodimm: 31.0 C gpu: nvidia temp: 44 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-develop.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
           1: deb http://packages.linuxmint.com uma main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main
           2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
           3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
           6: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/speedtest.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu/ focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list 
           1: deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list 
           1: deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
Processes: CPU top: 5 
           1: cpu: 5.0% command: brave pid: 28871 mem: 347.9 MiB (1.0%) 
           2: cpu: 3.4% command: brave pid: 29271 mem: 162.8 MiB (0.5%) 
           3: cpu: 3.0% command: brave pid: 28905 mem: 184.3 MiB (0.5%) 
           4: cpu: 2.6% command: brave pid: 29048 mem: 172.6 MiB (0.5%) 
           5: cpu: 2.0% command: brave pid: 29021 mem: 138.0 MiB (0.4%) 
           Memory top: 5 
           1: mem: 531.6 MiB (1.6%) command: gnome-software pid: 5594 cpu: 0.1% 
           2: mem: 372.5 MiB (1.1%) command: xorg pid: 1454 cpu: 0.2% 
           3: mem: 347.9 MiB (1.0%) command: brave pid: 28871 cpu: 5.0% 
           4: mem: 301.0 MiB (0.9%) command: cinnamon pid: 4658 cpu: 0.2% 
           5: mem: 184.3 MiB (0.5%) command: brave pid: 28905 cpu: 3.0% 
Info:      Processes: 301 Uptime: 12h 24m Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 
           alt: 10/7/8/9 Shell: bash (sudo) v: 5.0.17 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

---

As a side note: I have many Optimus laptops (Intel + NVIDIA), and my main Dell is the only one requiring this for Suspend to work.

---

Bonus points requirement: 100 bonus points will be added to the best effort answer - does not need to be perfect, just dig in and *duckduck* anything that I missed and could possibly explain this GRUB2 modification working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GRUB2 line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
```

prevents the kernel to load the driver. The driver is then loaded by your display manager. Nothing more, nothing less.

My guess is that you have `noveau` in the kernel, but have the binary blob from NVIDIA installed too. In case you block kernel loading the `noveau` driver, the suspend starts working as the binary NVIDIA drivers are loaded instead.